# WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() equivalent for the platform/ host side

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

Is there a way to **ensure the bindings are initialized** between Flutter and Host/ Platform (Android, iOS)? I want to do this because I want to invoke methods from host to dart.

For example, in Android (java), I create a flutter engine, register plugins, and create a method channel, and launch the application:

```java
FlutterEngine flutterEngine = new FlutterEngine(context, null);
// Remember to register plugins
GeneratedPluginRegister.registerGeneratedPlugins(flutterEngine);
DartExecutor executor = flutterEngine.getDartExecutor();
methodChannel = new MethodChannel(executor.getBinaryMessenger(), "my background method channel");
methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);

// Launch app
DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint appEntrypoint = DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault();
executor.executeDartEntrypoint(appEntrypoint);
```

I'd like to use `methodChannel.invokeMethod`, but the application might not be ready for me yet, even though in appEntrypoint, the same MethodChannel is created on the dart side. If I call `methodChannel.invokeMethod` too early, I get:

```
2021-09-14 16:41:01.102 30103-30425/com.example.app E/flutter: 
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
 MissingPluginException
  (No implementation found for method MethodName on channel com.example.app.package)
```

A solution would be to ask the Dart side to call a PlatformMethod when it's ready initializing, which would inform me that it's ready to receive messages. But I would prefer to avoid having to set up 2 way communication if I only need to send one message to the Dart side.

I have a feeling it's not possible. If so, could someone still explain why the binding has to be awaited from the Dart side? Something to do with no listeners available on the Platform side?

Answer (score 1):

### The methods were actually being called.

It was working. This was a bad idea, but the actual methods were being called: the 2 Method Channels on dart side and 2 method channels on Platform side were calling each other just fine. They all had the same channel name. Probably **not** a good idea for complexity reasons (see below), but it worked.

### My specific issue:

The reason I was getting `No implementation found for method MethodName` was exactly because I had **two** MethodChannels on the dart side, and **two** on Platform side. I was recreating the same isolate, so I had 2 Flutter applications running **simultaneously**. When one Isolate called a dart method I did not implement on on Method Call Handler on Platform side, I got this error.

### Lesson learnt

If you have separate components on your app (Android components: Activity, Service, Broadcast Receiver or Dart Isolates):

- Don't re-create the main application entrypoint. Create a new separate DartEntrypoint.
- Use unique channel names for the `MethodChannel`.

Comment: Hi @Ben I am having the same issue, especially with the path provider and work manager I can't seem to make it work. I am getting the same error, No implementation found for method